# jQuery have text slide to the left and fade out

Tags: jquery, html

I working with jquery to have text slide out to the left, but at the end, the text is still there, I am looking to have the text go off the page completely.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.overlay').delay(5000).animate({
                height: 'toggle'
                }, 1000, function() {
        }); 
        $('.overlay-text').delay(4900).animate({ width: '50%', height: '50%' }, 'slow');
});
```

and HTML

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-text">
                                Text
                        </div><!--overlay-text-->
                </div><!--overlay-->
                <div class="second-overlay">
                        <div class="second-overlay-text left">
                                More Text
                        </div><!--second-overlay-text-left-->
                        <div class="second-overlay-text right">
                                More Text
                        </div><!--second-overlay-text-right-->
                </div><!--second-overlay-->
        </div><!--container-->
```

How do I get the first text to slide off the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/hh27b60n/

Comment: I might've misunderstood, but is this what you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/hry6vpjv/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/hh27b60n/4/ I slowed the animation down so you could see what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to the .overlay-text and .container

Then change your animate to:

```
$('.overlay-text').delay(300).animate({ left: "-999px" }, 'slow');
```

This will slide the text off the page

http://jsfiddle.net/2f5gnb5g/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had success by animating the element's CSS for `right` instead of `width`:

Added `position:relative` to the text element to give it position:

```css
.overlay-text {
    position:relative;
    ...
}
```

```js
$('.overlay-text').delay(4900).animate({ right: '100%' }, 'slow');
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hh27b60n/2/)

### EDIT

I forgot about the fading out. I'll do that by adding "opacity" to the CSS and animation:

```css
.overlay-text {
    position:relative;
    opacity:1;
    ...
}
```

```js
$('.overlay-text').delay(4900).animate({
    right: '100%',
    opacity:0
}, 'slow');
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hh27b60n/6/)